# How do I get the filename from a tempfile object?

Tags: python, csv, temporary-files

My goal is to create a temporary file that's written by csv.writer which will be used in an upload to a database. Once the upload completes, I want to delete the file.

The upload and deletion portions are not included here as I haven't fully built it out but I need to get past this part first.

```
import csv, io, tempfile

filename = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.csv', delete=False)

file = io.StringIO(report_downloader.DownloadReportAsString(report, skip_report_header=False, skip_column_header=False, skip_report_summary=True))
reader = csv.reader(file)

with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerows([row])
```

The resulting error from doing this is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "aw-ad-performance-tempfile.py", line 99, in <module> get_api_report()
File "aw-ad-performance-tempfile.py", line 92, in get_api_report
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:'<tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper object at 0x00000274FBED0FD0>'
```

I've tried a few different ways of addressing the problem and I've identified that it expects a string where filename is here:

```
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
```

Is it possible to reference the temporary file as a string using the tempfile module so csv.writer recognizes it? What's the syntax to do so if it is?

Comment: Hello mnjt, and welcome to the site.  This site works best when you keep it to one question per question, so I removed the second one from here.  Feel free to edit your question again if you aren't happy with the changes, or to ask the second part of your question with a new question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're on the right track. You need reference your file with the `.name` attribute of your `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` object.  See the documentation [here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html)

```
with open(filename.name, 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerows([row])
```

Comment: When I test that out no file is produced in the directory although the script executes successfully. Is it possible that it's ignoring my delete=False somehow by referencing it in the csv.writer module?

I tested with a static file name and it creates the file with no issue.

Comment: @mnjt  Are you able to watch the directory as the script runs?  Try putting a `time.sleep(10)` call in your `with` loop to stall the script.

Comment: I'm able to watch it. I added in your snippet and monitored the directory as the script ran. Nothing changed in the directory itself. I monitored while using a string after that to make sure I didn't simply miss it or make an error adding in `time.sleep(10)`. I'm able to very easily create the file using `with open('test1.csv'...)` as an example.

Comment: @mnjt I'm not able to recreate this on my side, the temp file is remaining after the script runs.  Are you sure you're looking for it in the right place?  `print filename.name` should tell you where it's at.  If that doesn't help maybe ask a new question with all the details and I'll take a look.

Comment: I tweaked a few things to answer my follow-up, so deleted and posting this to say it works and thanks! I was indeed looking in the wrong place.